# Element inside <aura:if> returns undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute

I'm experiencing a weird issue when trying cmp.find('id') with elements inside and outside `<aura:if>`. Here is the code:

```
<aura:attribute name="editMode" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<div class="slds">
    <ui:inputText aura:id="text1" class="slds-input" value="11223" disabled="true"/>

    <div class="slds-modal__content">      
        <ui:inputText aura:id="text2" class="slds-input" value="11223" disabled="true"/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.editMode}">
        <ui:inputText aura:id="text1" class="slds-input" value="11223" disabled="true"/>
    </aura:if>
```

JS Controller:

```
console.log("text1: "+cmp.find("text1"));
console.log("text2: "+cmp.find("text2"));
console.log("text3: "+cmp.find("text3"));
```

Console:

> text1: markup://ui:inputText {8:557;a} {text1}
>   text2: markup://ui:inputText {8:557;a} {text2}
>   text1: undefined

**Note**:

- The first time it runs, none of them is undefined.
- The second time, last one (inside `aura:if`) is undefined.
- editMode is set to true in helper's `init` so assume it's always `true`.
- If I use `<aura:if isTrue="true">` or `editMode` attribute's default is true, it always runs fine and all values are "defined"

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You provide same id for two input text. Change the Id of the last one input text and try it again may be it work properly.

Thanks.